# Oracle SQL update statement where column starts with x

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Let's say I have this data:

```
ID      | NAME     | FRUIT
--------------------------
1       | abc_v1   | apple
2       | abc_v2   | banana
3       | abc_v3   | cherry
4       | xyz_v1   | banana
5       | xyz_v2   | grape
6       | xyz_v3   | apple
```

For each row, I want to replace the value in the FRUIT column with whatever's in the FRUIT column for the row with the smallest ID where the first four characters of NAME are the same.

So since the first three rows all have a NAME that starts with "abc_", I want all three of those rows to have "apple" in the FRUIT column, since that's the value where ID is the lowest. Similarly, I want the last three rows to all have the value "banana" in the FRUIT column, which is the FRUIT value in row 4, the lowest ID where NAME starts with "xyz_".

My real table has 16K rows. Each has a unique ID, and each will have a NAME that starts with the same four characters as zero or more other rows.

In really bad pseudocode, I want something like this:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET FRUIT = 
    (SELECT FRUIT FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 
    (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME LIKE 
    [some way to represent first four characters]%));
```

Can I do this in a single SQL update statement in Oracle? I'm stuck on the part I put in brackets above; I feel like I'll need a variable that loops through all the rows, which makes me think maybe I need a PL/SQL program.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: WHERE FRUIT LIKE SUBSTR(FRUIT,1,4)||'%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that `id` is a primary key in `MYTABLE`

```
MERGE INTO MYTABLE m
USING (
      SELECT m.*,
           first_value( fruit ) 
              over (partition by substr(name,1,4) order by id ) As new_fruit
      FROM MYTABLE m
) x
ON (x.id = m.id )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET m.fruit = x.new_fruit;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!